# python3でCGIを動かしているのですが、ゴミ文字が入るエラーが出ます

Tags: python3

python3でCGIサーバーを試しているのですがエラーが出てしまいます。

CGIサーバーは下記で起動しています。

```
python -m http.server --bind localhost --cgi 8000
```

そして、以下のファイルをlocalhostから呼び出すと添付画像のような表示がなされます。
11 とか　0　というどこにもないはずの数字が紛れ込んでいます。

```
import sys,os
import io

sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer,encoding='utf-8')

print('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n')
print('Hello, World!')
```

[image: 表示結果]

更にプリント部分を以下の様にして実行したところ、表示が真っ白で何も表示されなくなりました。

```
print("""<!doctype html>
<html>
<HEAD>
<Content-Type:'text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
</HEAD>
<body>
test
test2
</body>
</html>""")
```

そんなに複雑なものではないはずなのにうまく動かず、
何がおかしいのか分からず困り果てています。

どうかよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

当て推量ですが、

```
print('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n')
```

を

```
print('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n')
```

に変更すると直ったりしませんでしょうか。レスポンスヘッダとレスポンスボディの間に空行が1つ必要です。

Comment: ありがとうございました！ １行あけるようにすると正常に表示されました。cgiをきちんと勉強するようにします！

Answer (score 0):

> 添付画像のような表示がなされます。
>   11 とか　0　というどこにもないはずの数字が紛れ込んでいます。

質問文に確認手段が記載されていないため当てずっぽうですが[`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding)になっているのではないでしょうか。この場合、リンク先Exampleに書かれているような結果になるため、`11`や`0`が観測されるのは正常な動作です。
（改行が消えているのはHTMLとして解釈されているから？ なんにしても確認手段が不明なことにはよくわかりません。）

現行のHTTP/1.1では信頼性とコネクションの再利用のために`Content-Length`が不明なレスポンスでは`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`を使用してレスポンスの終端を検出できるようになっています。

> 更にプリント部分を以下の様にして実行したところ、表示が真っ白で何も表示されなくなりました。

こちらはこちらで完全な手順が提示されていないため当てずっぽうですがHTTPヘッダーが出力されていないから受信側でコンテンツを検出できていないのではないでしょうか。